# Scrape data from dropdown menu and "More Results" web pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the product info for each item per sales category for a certain company. Here's the URL I'm working with:

https://www.lushusa.com/bath-shower/

I'm at the point where I've pulled all the data that's visible per product. What I'm having trouble with is twofold:

1. I can't seem to figure out how to get the data from the dropdown menus for the items that have multiple options.
2. how to automate my scrape to get data for every product given the "More Results" button. I notice there's an event with the Network tab in Dev Tools but can't wrap my mind around it.

Here's the code I have so far with the resulting dictionary:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json

#Need to extract:
#Product Name
#Product Category
#Seasonal/Bestseller/Cult Classic
#Vegan/Not
#Sizes/Weights
#Prices (can't get last two from dataanalytics--check dropdown instead)

def listitems_to_strings(lst):
    list_text = [str(lst[i]) for i in range(0, len(lst))]
    return list_text

def create_dict(scrape_list):
    scrape_data = list()
    
    for html_item in scrape_list:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_item, "html.parser").find("div", {"class": "impressions"})
        scrape_data.append(json.loads(soup["data-impressions"]))
    
    return scrape_data

def html_to_dict(url):
    raw_html = req.get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.content, 'html.parser')
    scrape = html_soup.select('.impressions')
    scrape = listitems_to_strings(scrape)
    
    return create_dict(scrape)
    
url = html_to_dict('https://www.lushusa.com/bath-shower/')
print(url)
```

Result:

```
[{'id': '00232', 'name': 'Ocean Salt', 'price': 21.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Face And Body Scrub', 'variant': '4.2 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/face/cleansers-scrubs/ocean-salt/9999902128.html', 'dimension11': 'Cult classics badge', 'dimension12': '', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '00157', 'name': 'Sex Bomb', 'price': 7.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bombs', 'variant': '6.3 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/sex-bomb/9999900157.html', 'dimension11': '', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '07188', 'name': 'Scrubee', 'price': 9.25, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Body Butter', 'variant': '3.1 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/shower/body-butters-conditioners/scrubee/9999907188.html', 'dimension11': 'Cult classics badge', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Melts', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '02223', 'name': 'I Want A Hippopotamus For Christmas', 'price': 5.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bomb', 'variant': '3.1 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/i-want-a-hippopotamus-for-christmas/9999902223.html', 'dimension11': 'Christmas Badge', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '02218', 'name': 'Snowman Dreaming', 'price': 5.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bomb', 'variant': '3.1 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/snowman-dreaming/9999902218.html', 'dimension11': 'Christmas Badge', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 0, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '03157', 'name': 'Twilight', 'price': 7.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bomb', 'variant': '6.3 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/twilight/9999903157.html', 'dimension11': 'Bestseller badge', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '02217', 'name': 'Winter Garden', 'price': 5.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bomb', 'variant': '3.1 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/winter-garden/9999902217.html', 'dimension11': 'Christmas Badge', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '09208', 'name': 'Deep Sleep', 'price': 8.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bomb', 'variant': '7 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/deep-sleep/9999909208.html', 'dimension11': '', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '05551', 'name': 'Cup O´ Coffee', 'price': 12.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Face And Body Mask', 'variant': '5.2 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/face/masks/cup-o%C2%B4-coffee/9999905552.html', 'dimension11': '', 'dimension12': 'Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '02209', 'name': 'Bat Art', 'price': 6.45, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bomb', 'variant': '3.8 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/bat-art/9999902209.html', 'dimension11': 'Halloween Badge', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 2, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '00012', 'name': 'Butterball', 'price': 5.25, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bath Bomb', 'variant': '3.1 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bath-bombs/butterball/9999900012.html', 'dimension11': '', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '03821', 'name': 'Dream Cream', 'price': 7.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Body Lotion', 'variant': '1.7 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/body/body-lotions/dream-cream/9999900031.html', 'dimension11': 'Cult classics badge', 'dimension12': 'Vegan', 'dimension13': 0, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '01920', 'name': 'Sleepy', 'price': 12.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Bubble Bar', 'variant': '7 oz.', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/bath/bubble-bars/sleepy/9999901920.html', 'dimension11': '', 'dimension12': 'Naked,Self Preserving,Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}, {'id': '06025', 'name': 'Angels on Bare Skin', 'price': 16.95, 'brand': 'Lush', 'category': 'Face And Body Cleanser', 'variant': '3.5 oz', 'quantity': 1, 'list': '/face/cleansers/angels-on-bare-skin/9999906953.html', 'dimension11': 'Cult classics badge', 'dimension12': 'Vegan', 'dimension13': 1, 'dimension14': 1, 'dimension15': True}]
```

I would like to be at a point where I can append the additional size/weights to their respective list items.

I don't expect to have it answered *for* me, but a push in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to scrape all the results at once, try this (to scrape another category, just replace the cgid):

```
url = html_to_dict('https://www.lushusa.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Lush-Site/default/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=bath-shower&start=0&sz=10000')
```

And for the data with drop-down, you should check the class `custom-select form-control select-size selectpicker` for the size, and from there check every tag `option`, you'll find the value as "price / size". Example:

```
<select class="custom-select form-control select-size selectpicker " aria-label="size" data-attr="size" id="size-9999902128-1">
    <option value="https://www.lushusa.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Lush-Site/default/Product-VariationPLP?dwvar_9999902128_size=4.2%20oz.&amp;pid=9999902128&amp;quantity=1" data-attr-value="4.2 oz." selected="" class=" selected">$21.95 / 4.2 oz. </option>
    <option value="https://www.lushusa.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Lush-Site/default/Product-VariationPLP?dwvar_9999902128_size=10.2%20oz.&amp;pid=9999902128&amp;quantity=1" data-attr-value="10.2 oz." class=" "> $37.95 / 10.2 oz. </option>
    <option value="https://www.lushusa.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-Lush-Site/default/Product-VariationPLP?dwvar_9999902128_size=21.8%20oz.&amp;pid=9999902128&amp;quantity=1" data-attr-value="21.8 oz." class=" "> $49.95 / 21.8 oz. </option>
</select>
```

Note that in the value " $49.95 / 21.8 oz. " I removed extra spaces and line breaks for a clean display.